# Dynamically add function declaration in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm new to TypeScript and tried to implement a auto-generated builder pattern so that I can write something along the lines of

```js
class Foo {
    @buildable('inBar')
    public bar = 'Uninitialized';

    constructor() {}
}

const FooBuilder = getBuilder<Foo>(Foo);

const foo = new FooBuilder().inBar('My Bar').build();
```

Writing [the code](https://gist.github.com/milgner/7c872216f1e538ad6b192d8b59447a41) for this was more or less straightforward, considering that not only am I new to TS but also been away from JS for some time.

But of course now the transpiler complains about not knowing the `inBar` function. I could use the `[]` operator like `const foo = new FooBuilder()['inBar']('My Bar').build();` but that kind of syntax somewhat defeats the purpose of having a builder pattern in the first place, which is supposed to improve readability.

Is there some way to dynamically add functions to a type? Maybe using the `reflect-metadata` API?
I'm aware that decorators are not supposed to add methods to the decorated class but in this case I'm trying to dynamically create a new class in order to avoid having to write and maintain all the boilerplate code associated with the builder class. Being able to dynamically add a type declaration would be quite useful here.

Comment: I suppose, [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881) is exactly what are you asking about. For this moment, you should directly extend type of your class with decorator fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending type when extending an ES6 class with a TypeScript decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54892401/extending-type-when-extending-an-es6-class-with-a-typescript-decorator)

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance i don't see how this question relate to one you ref. You suggesting this is also impossible?

Comment: @hackape the meta of this questions are simillar. Decorators does not (yet, according to issue I have mentioned) exend types of entities on which they are being used, so, basically, this question is simillar to one I have mentioned, I suppose :) Of course, as I said in first comment, I think there is only one way to achieve this - extend types manually. I asked something simillar question about `Array<SomeType>` decorated with `@observable` from `mobx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS is very dynamic, however TS is not. Regarding the typing system in TS, it's mostly functional, or pure. AFAIK the only *side-effect-ish* feature is [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html). Dynamically adding declaration depends on this feature.

The idea is simply: as you dynamically create `builders` on JS side, to reflect these on-going events accordingly, you should also "dynamically" expand the registry interface on TS side.

Here's the gist. Check this [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20BuilderRegistry%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aconst%20builderRegistry%3A%20IBuilderRegistry%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20any%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Builder%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20ctor%20%3D%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20propertyNames%3A%20Array%3Cstring%3E%20%3D%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20properties%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20build()%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20builderDef%20%3D%20Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20instance%20%3D%20new%20builderDef.ctor()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(const%20prop%20of%20builderDef.propertyNames)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20instance%5Bprop%5D%20%3D%20this.properties%5Bprop%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20instance%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createBuilder%3CT%3E(ctor%3A%20Function)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20clz%20%3D%20class%20extends%20Builder%3CT%3E%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20clz.ctor%20%3D%20ctor.constructor%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20clz.propertyNames%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20clz%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20buildable(name%3F%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function(target%3A%20any%2C%20propertyKey%3A%20string%20%7C%20symbol)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20className%20%3D%20target.constructor.name%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(!builderRegistry%5BclassName%5D)%20%7B%20builderRegistry%5BclassName%5D%20%3D%20createBuilder(target)%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20builderFunctionName%20%3D%20name%20%7C%7C%20propertyKey%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20builder%20%3D%20builderRegistry%5BclassName%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20builder.prototype%5BbuilderFunctionName%5D%20%3D%20function(value%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.properties%5BpropertyKey%5D%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20builder.propertyNames.push(propertyKey)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getBuilder%3CT%20extends%20keyof%20IBuilderRegistry%3E(ctor%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20builder%20%3D%20builderRegistry%5Bctor.name%20as%20T%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20builder%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IBuilderRegistry%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'Foo'%3A%20%7B%20new()%3A%20IFooBuilder%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IFooBuilder%20extends%20Builder%3CFoo%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20inBar(val%3A%20string)%3A%20IFooBuilder%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40buildable('inBar')%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20bar%20%3D%20'Uninitialized'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20FooBuilder%20%3D%20getBuilder%3C'Foo'%3E(Foo)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20foo%20%3D%20new%20FooBuilder().inBar('My%20Bar').build()%3B%0D%0A) for full example.

```js
// Empty interface, to be expanded later
interface BuilderRegistry {}
const builderRegistry: IBuilderRegistry = {} as any

class Foo {
    @buildable('inBar')
    public bar = 'Uninitialized';
    constructor() {}
}

interface IFooBuilder extends Builder<Foo> {
    inBar(val: string): IFooBuilder
}

// Expand IBuilderRegistry interface
interface IBuilderRegistry {
    'Foo': { new(): IFooBuilder }
}

const FooBuilder = getBuilder<'Foo'>(Foo);
const foo = new FooBuilder().inBar('My Bar').build(); // all good
```

Comment: I have another post about TS trick that leverage declaration merging, featuring a more apt example. If you're interested you can [read it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55694876/3617380).

Comment: And yes, that is exactly what I meant :D